# Direct Delta Function

Tags: mathematical-physics

I was reading a Mathematics for Physics book when I saw these exercises. By using the knowledge of direct delta function, show that:

$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta '(x-y)dx=-f'(y)$

$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x-y)dx=f(y)$

I have been working on those for quite sometime, but I can't solve simply because I don't understand much about direct delta function. Could you help me please?

Comment: What facts are you given about the Dirac delta function?  That is, what is your definition of it?  Typically, those two properties are proven using "the sifting property", i.e. the fact that $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x)dx=f(0)$. This is considered to be the defining property.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, What I mean is the book asks me to derive those properties. They want me to show that it is true.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x)\,dx=f(0)$?  If not, *what is the definition of the Dirac delta function*?

Comment: No, I can't. But I have just found a way to derive that one.

Comment: *What is your textbook's definition of the Dirac delta function?*  If we're not starting from the sifting property, where are we starting?

Comment: I think I got $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x)dx=f(0)$ covered. Thank you for telling me about sifting property. I only have $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta '(x-y)dx=-f'(y)$ and $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x-y)dx=f(y)$ to finish.

Comment: My book definition of DDF is the $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x)dx=f(0)$. I think they kind of like OK, I introduced you about definition, and now you learn how to derive it.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's what I expected. To show that $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x-y)\,dx=f(y)$, it specifically helps to make the $u$-substitution (change of variables) $u = x-y \implies du = dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the fact that $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }f(x)\delta (x)\,dx=f(0)$, show that the second equality holds by using $u$-substitution.  Then, show that the first equality holds using integration by parts.

Comment: I did it. Thank to you.